# Этимология слова "засучить"

Tags: этимология

Точнее, меня интересует, родственно ли это слово таким, как "сук, сучок", "сучка" и т.д.? И еще, что оно значило изначально?
Спасибо

Comment: Как всегда, получила удовольствие от ответа Софии.
Всё остальное - говорильня пустая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Засучить - завернуть кверху (рукав, штанину). От глагола сучить/скать (исконное), от ст.-сл. "съкати" - свивать в одну нить несколько прядей, также "скань" - узоры, сплетенные из проволок. Перенос и расширение значения по сходству: скручивать,закручивать, также мять, сжимать, перебирать, двигать взад и вперед (сучить ножками - о ребенке), то есть совершать разнообразные движения.

Слова "сук, сучок" происходят от о.-с. слова соха (socha)- сук с развилиной, в др-рус. только с 15 века соха - это орудие пахоты, в русских говорах до недавнего времени соха- это цельная лесина с развилиной, также "сохатый" - о лосе, исходное значение "развилистый, вилообразный".

Сука - самка домашней собаки, от о.-с. "suka", где "k" - суффикс, сравнить suns (латыш.), sun (арм.) - собака. Слово в этимологическом значении не очень ясное.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы спокойно приблизил слово "сук" к "соучастию". Сук - соучастник ствола, соучастник роста древа.  Т.к. слово "засучить" становится полноценным, приобретающим смысл, лишь в связке со словом "рукава", можно сделать вывод, что это сленговое выражение, с чьей-то лёгкой руки вошедшее в обиход. Есть слова: "сучкоруб"- человек, освобождающий ствол дерева от сучков, и "сучковать"- собственно, процесс, производимый сучкорубом. Процесс этот достаточно тяжёлый и трудоёмкий, к которому и следует подходить именно засучив рукава, т.е. серьёзно и решительно. Возможжно, в среде лесорубов и зародилось это выражение. Засучив рукава, ты освобождаешь руки, при этом становится легче махать топором.

Comment: Полная ерунда ! Вы , дорогой "Саша" , наверное действительно "дурак" ... Профессиональная должность "сучкоруб" появилась только вместе со становлением лесной отрасли промышленности , и , к тому же , известна только тем , кто хоть как-то связан с лесозаготовками . Я сам бывший работник леспромхоза (Басковский ЛПХ в Пермском крае) , и мне прекрасно известны слова "сучкоруб" , "чекеровщик" , "вальщик" , "трелевщик" . Но для большинства людей услышать слово "сучкоруб" случается не чаще , чем , скажем , слово "штехшталмейстер" .   "Засучить рукава" появилось абсолютно независимо от "сучкоруба" .

Comment: Это всего лишь моё предположение, подобное словосочетание могло появиться в любой другой профессиональной среде. С удовольствием выслушал бы версию такого знающего и мудрого человека, как вы. И, всё же, нтересно, а кто рубил сучки лет 500 назад? Или избы строили из ветвей?

Comment: Сучки-то , батенька , рубили и 500-т лет назад и 1000-чу ! Да только профессионально-штатная должность с названием  "сучкоруб" не могла появиться раньше , чем появился промышленно-отраслевой способ лесозаготовок . В вашем ответе ( как у комика Задорного) доминируют умозрительные фантазии , а не здравый смысл . То же самое относится и к вашему истолкованию слова "сучка" ... Или , по вашему разумению , этноним "башкир" произошёл от слова "башка" ?! Башкиры - народ большеголовый , головастый , башковитый (по сравнению с другими народами) , - да ?! Посмейтесь вместе со мной !

Comment: Я бы пока оставил башкиров в покое и вернулся к сучкам. Если их всё же рубили 500 лет назад, не взирая на отсутствие штатной должности, как называли этих людей?

Comment: Уважаемый следопыт, выбирайте, пожалуйста выражения и не переходите на оскорбления других пользователей, даже если не согласны с их мнением.